# Buttons not appearing below image in python GUI

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I am developing a GUI on Python and I have the following problem: I want to have the picture at the top of the window and buttons right underneath it. I am using the Tkinter module and whatever geometry I use (place, pack or grid) the buttons don't move. The are only displayed if I move the image using grid to row 1 (which is the second row), otherwise they don't appear at all. Here is the code I am using for now. For reference the picture has dimensions of 291x87 pixels.

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *

def main():
    window =Tk()
    window.geometry("300x300")
    window.title("Dienes Blocks Application")
    window.iconbitmap(default='favicon.ico')
    app = HomeScreen(window)
    window.mainloop()

class HomeScreen(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.create_buttons()
        self.sparx_head()


    def sparx_head(self):
        self.grid()
        photo = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="logosmall.gif")
        sparx_header = Label(image=photo)
        sparx_header.image = photo # keep a reference!
        sparx_header.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, sticky='NSEW')

    def create_buttons(self):
        self.grid()
        #teacher button
        teacher_button = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Teacher")
        teacher_button.grid(column=0, row=10)
        # student button
        student_button = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Student")
        student_button.grid(column=2, row=10)
        # prototype button
        prototype_button = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Prototype")
        prototype_button.grid(column=1, row=10)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `self` in the image label:

```
sparx_header = Label(self,image=photo)
```

They were not having the same parent & that's why you were having this problem

Comment: Hi @user3704051 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.